# Xceed PropertyGrid: How to Hide Fully Qualified Name for ExpandableObject

Tags: propertygrid, wpf-extended-toolkit

In Xceed's Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid, how do I hide the fully-qualified name of the expandable object? (see screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot of ExpandableObject example from Xceed documentation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the ToString() method on your expandable object.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
}
```